# ”workItem -create API”を用いhttp通信でAzureDevOspにタスク登録でのエラー

Tags: api, azure

workItem -create API
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=5.0に
①PersonalAccessToken
②URL内の3か所　　を入力したがレスポンスが203エラー

・聞きたいこと
1．Personal Access TokenでAPIを使えるのか
2．上記APIでAzureDevOspにタスク登録できるのか
3．2が可能ならURLに追加で入力すべき項目はあるか

お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

1. はい、PATでREST APIが使えます。PATはbase64エンコードしておいてください
2. 今手元でなぜかVS CodeのREST Clientが動かないのですが、行けるはずです。ただ、今APIは[5.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)になっているので、変更されたほうがいいかもしれません(まだリタイアするとはアナウンスはないはずですが)
3. それで最低限のwork itemは作れますが、中身はほぼからになるので、BODYでタイトルくらいはつけたほうがいいでしょう。